# Form's children not available in $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a form like :

```
<form name="myform">
  <input type="text" name="input" />
</form>
```

But my input is not available in `$scope.myform.input` and neither by `{{ myform.input }}`. I tried to add a `ng-minlength`:

```
<form name="myform" novalidate>
  <input type="text" name="input" ng-minlength="10" />
</form>
```

And even by typing something shorter than 10, `myform` is still valid. It's like the input is not part of the form at all.

Here is an example hosted on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/saag0agc/

AngularJS Documentation on input text: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D

Answer (score 0):

You need an *ng-model* attribute. For example:

```
<form name="myform">
  <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="input" />
</form>
```

Then you can access the content via:

```
{{ input }}
```

Although I would suggest using a name/model other than *input*.

Comment: Take a look at my comment on SergeL's answer. You're absolutely right, input is a pretty bad name for an... input. This is just an example ^^

Comment: *ng-model* is the only non-optional argument listed in the docs. The example in the docs for input[text] includes *ng-model*. If you remove it in their Plunker example, it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

The ng-model property is missing on the input.

```
<form name="myform">
  <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="myform.input" />
</form>
```

Comment: Forms children are supposed to be accessible within the form in $scope without assigning them through ng-model. Take a look at the doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D

They are displaying {{ myForm.input }} and not {{ text }}.